# pass a call by reference as call by value

Tags: javascript, html

I've been using this code to move *ImageId* to *jCrop*

But `_ImageId` variable is given by reference.

How can I give `_ImageId` variable to the *jCrop* by value?

```
    var _ImageId = 0;

    $(document).ready(
    function(){    
        $('.page .image').attr("id", function(){  
        _ImageId = $(this).attr("id");
        return $(this).attr("id");
    }).Jcrop({
        ImageId : _ImageId,  // my problem is here , when _ImageId change , all of them will change 
        onSelect: Page_ImageSelected
    });      
}
```

Comment: All javascript values are passed by value, even if they are references to objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little ... "weird".

Maybe you should try something like that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.page .image').each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        element.Jcrop({
            ImageId : element.attr('id'),
            onSelect: Page_ImageSelected
        });
    });
}​);​
```

Javascript use a "by value" call when you are using "simple" types like number, integer, float, string, boolean ...

The problem here is your code.

Comment: even I think your code should works  , but it do not work anyway , evern It do not run until  var element = $(this);

Comment: So maybe your selector `.page .image` is wrong. But i can't tell without your html code.

Answer (score 0):

You already *do* pass the `_ImageId` by value, the `JCrop` method will receive an object whose `ImageId` property *is* `0` (or the value assigned in the `attr` callback) and will not change when `_ImageId` is changed.

Comment: When do it change, what do you think changes it? Of course the property might change, but not from assignments to `_ImageId`